# apk seen as non-system when signing it with 2 platform keys with apksigner

Tags: android, package, apk, signature, apksigner

When I sign my .apk with 2 platform keys (2 pairs of .pem & .pk8 files for 2 different platforms) with apksigner, the app itself is not seen anymore as a system-app on either of the 2 platforms I signed it for.

But when I try to sign it using just one platform key (1 pair of .pem & .pk8 files for a single platform) with apksigner, the app is seen as a system-app on that respective platform I signed it for.

The command I'm using is

```
apksigner sign
   --verbose --v1-signer-name PLATFORM1 --v3-signing-enabled false --v4-signing-enabled false --key platform1.pk8 --cert platform1.x509.pem
   --next-signer
   --verbose --v1-signer-name PLATFORM2 --v3-signing-enabled false --v4-signing-enabled false --key platform2.pk8 --cert platform2.x509.pem
   platform1-and-platform2-signed.apk
```

Similarly, the commands I'm using when signing the .apk for each platform independently are:

```
apksigner sign
   --verbose --v1-signer-name PLATFORM1 --v3-signing-enabled false --v4-signing-enabled false --key platform1.pk8 --cert platform1.x509.pem
   platform1-signed.apk
```

&

```
apksigner sign
   --verbose --v1-signer-name PLATFORM2 --v3-signing-enabled false --v4-signing-enabled false --key platform2.pk8 --cert platform2.x509.pem
   platform2-signed.apk
```

I checked my doubled-signed .apk (`platform1-and-platform2-signed.apk`) against both `keytool -printcert` & `apksigner verify --print-certs` commands and they both output good information (AFAIK):

```
Signer #1:

Signature:

Owner: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Serial number: <first-serial-number>
Valid from: Wed Apr 16 01:40:50 EEST 2008 until: Sun Sep 02 01:40:50 EEST 2035
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: <first-sha1>
     SHA256: <second-sha256>
Signature algorithm name: MD5withRSA (disabled)
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<first-KeyIdentifier>
]
[EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US]
SerialNumber: [    <apairof8hexadigits>]
]

#2: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen: no limit
]

#3: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<first-KeyIdentifier>
]
]


Signer #2:

Signature:

Owner: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Serial number: <second-serial-number>
Valid from: Tue Dec 23 08:43:41 EET 2014 until: Sat May 10 09:43:41 EEST 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: <second-sha1>
     SHA256: <second-sha256>
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<second-KeyIdentifier>
]
]

#2: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen: no limit
]

#3: ObjectId: <ObjectId-prefix>.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<second-KeyIdentifier>
]
]



Warning:
The certificate uses the MD5withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk and is disabled.
```

&

```
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v3.1 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3.1): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 2
Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: <first-certificate-SHA-256-digest>
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: <first-certificate-SHA-1-digest>
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: <first-certificate-MD5-digest>
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: <first-public-key-SHA-256-digest>
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: <first-public-key-SHA-1-digest>
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: <first-public-key-MD5-digest>
Signer #2 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=android@android.com, CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Android, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #2 certificate SHA-256 digest: <second-certificate-SHA256-digest>
Signer #2 certificate SHA-1 digest: <second-certificate-SHA1-digest>
Signer #2 certificate MD5 digest: <second-certificate-MD5-digest>
Signer #2 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #2 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #2 public key SHA-256 digest: <second-public-key-SHA256-digest>
Signer #2 public key SHA-1 digest: <second-public-key-SHA1-digest>
Signer #2 public key MD5 digest: <second-public-key-MD5-digest>
WARNING: META-INF/INDEX.LIST not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.support.design_material.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.activity_activity.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.annotation_annotation-experimental.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat-resources.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.arch.core_core-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.cardview_cardview.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.core_core-ktx.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.core_core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.media_media.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.print_print.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.savedstate_savedstate.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.transition_transition.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.google.android.material_material.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.CompressionCodec not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.io.Deserializer not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/io.jsonwebtoken.io.Serializer not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/app-metadata.properties not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

I also tried the `--append-signature` parameter of apksigner tool, as of SDK 31.0.0 onwards, but the result of that attempt did not verify against `apksigner verify --print-certs` command with the following error output:

```
DOES NOT VERIFY
ERROR: APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #1: APK integrity check failed. CHUNKED_SHA256 digest mismatch. Expected: <expected-sha256>, actual: <actual-sha256>
```

I searched both SHA256 (expected & actual) inside the output from `keytool -printcert` and I didn't find them. Also, when I tried to deploy the .apk signed like this on the device, I got yet another error:

```
17:58   Failed to commit install session 1406340558 with command package install-commit 1406340558. Error: PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES:
            Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1406340558.tmp/0_AppName-_______-debug:
            Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1406340558.tmp/0_AppName-_______-debug using APK Signature Scheme v2:
            Failed to parse/verify signer #2 block: SHA-256 contents digest does not match the digest specified by a preceding signer

17:58   Error
            Installation did not succeed.
            The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
            Retry
```

One last thing, about the `--append-signature` parameter related attempt, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73507736/14273827) (about adding a new signature to an existing app) where a commenter is saying the following:

> apksigner in sdk 31.0.0 has a new feature: --append-signature. By this feature , a new signature can be appended into the signed apk and the previous signature will not be removed.
>
> However, if one is system signature, another is 3rd party signature, the apk will become non-system signature.

so, if I understand properly, with this 2nd method, even if I somehow managed to get the .apk verified by apksigner and deployed to device, the app itself would have still been seen as non-system by both platforms, because for each platform the other platform's key is non-system.

So my question is:

### How can I sign my .apk with both platform keys and have it seen as a system-app by both platforms?